# Multiple inheritance in C++: What is the good way to express the diagram in C++ with multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

What is the good way to express the diagram in C++ with multiple inheritance? Or do I need to use multiple inheritance in this case? Can't I just create a Child1 and a Child2 instance in the base class and use them?

[image]

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It is not clear from this diagram. If you want to connect child instances using common interface put it in the base class.

Comment: Yes. I want to connect the child classes. Can you show me outline of the code?

Comment: It depends how you want to connect the child cases.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the terms Base and Child correctly?  Because  your diagram seems to show that Base is composed of two Child objects, not that the Child classes inherit from Base.  Do you want the Child classes 'connected' in that they are similar?  Or 'connected' in that they can call methods on ("talk to") each other?

Comment: There will be connections from the base class to the child class also. The child classes are also connected in such a way that they can share information, change each others contents (i.e. variable values etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pseudo code but should illustrate the hierarchy:

Solution 1:

```
class IBaseInterface {}

class Base : IBaseInterface {}

class Child1 : Base {}

class Child2 : Base {}
```

Solution 2:

```
class IChildInterface {}

class Base {}

class Child1 : Base, IChildInterface  {}

class Child2 : Base, IChildInterface  {}
```

Comment: In Solution 1: Why there is IBaseInterface?

Comment: Because the interface is on the base class, so I called it that way. The two solutions are effectively: Have the interface which connects the child classes on the base class so the children inherit it or derive all children you want to connect from the interface.

Comment: yup. And deriving from IWhatever is pretty much always safe, so you won't need to do virtual inheritance and all that.

Answer (score 0):

"Can't I just create a Child1 and a Child2 instance in the base class and use them?"

I think what you are trying to achieve is this, no multiple inheritance required:

```
class IChildInterface {}

class Base { IChildInterface* child; }

class Child1: public IChildInterface
class Child2: public IChildInterface
```